# How to correctly make app structure to use resources?

Tags: java, resources, properties

can anyone tell me how to make directory structure of desktop app, to proper use of resources? Here is example of my app structure (using maven). It worked until I tryied to change packages structure, I only renames folders.

New structure:

**src/main/java/com/example/appname/app/App.java** //main class with Application, just runs gui
**src/main/java/com/example/appname/gui/GuiFrame.java** //JFrame

now I have resources this way, but it doesn't work:

**src/main/resources/com/example/appname/app/resources/App.properties**
**src/main/resources/com/example/appname/gui/resources/GuiFrame.properties**

after clean and build, netbeans makes me:

**target/classes/com/example/appname/app/App.class**
**target/classes/com/example/appname/app/resources/App.properties**
**target/classes/com/example/appname/gui/GuiFrame.class**
**target/classes/com/example/appname/gui/resources/GuiFrame.properties**

But when I run it, on Swing controls I don't see any text, which is inside .properties file, they are empty.

may I set something somewhere? Thank you for answers.

Comment: you are strongly suggested to use 'refactor' instead of simply renaming folders, so that the IDE can automatically update references to the renamed folders

Comment: I changed source packages by refatoring, but resources folders didn't reflected this new structure. They didn't changed.

Comment: The rename of resource package in Netbeans cause "The Rename refactoring cannot be aplied in this context"

Comment: it's a strange situation...anyway netbeans refactoring is not 100% perfect, i remember for example that if you rename a servlet in a java web project, netbeans (6.9) don't rename every reference in web.xml...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after your refactoring you need to change the way you load resources, i.e. from `getResourceAsStream("/App.properties")` to `getResourceAsStream("App.properties")`?